# Finding the value of the inverse function with inverse function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives

I am stuck by the following problem. 
Let $h:\Bbb R^2\rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ and 
$$h(x,y)= (x^2+3xy+xy^3, x^3-5y^2)$$

Let $g=h^{-1}$ near $(0,1)$. Find $Dg(0,-5)$

I showed that the inverse function theorem holds with $h$. But I cannot go on to solve this. Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $h(x_0,y_0) = (0,-5)$, then what is the relation between $Dg(0,-5)$ and $Dh(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: Did you find the Jacobian matrix?  Do you know how to find the inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix?

Comment: @RobertIsrael So then I should find the Jacobian, $Dh$, then invert it, and plug in the values (0,-5). But then why is there $(0,1)$ interval?

Comment: It's not the interval $(0,1)$, it's the point $(x=0,y=1)$.

Comment: You should first find the Jacobian, then plug in $x=0,y=1$, and **then** invert.

Comment: Then I create the function $g$ and differentiate that and then plug in (0,-5) thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness. By the chain rule we have that: $$g \circ h  = {\rm id} \implies D(g \circ h)_{(x,y)} = D({\rm id})_{(x,y)} \implies Dg_{h(x,y)} \circ Dh_{(x,y)} = {\rm id},$$ so: $$Dg_{h(x,y)} = (Dh_{(x,y)})^{-1}.$$Plugging $(x,y) = (0,1)$, we have: $$Dg_{h(0,1)} = (Dh_{(0,1)})^{-1} \implies Dg_{(0,5)} = (Dh_{(0,1)})^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0 \\ 0 & -10\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac 1 6 & 0  \\ 0 &-\frac 1 {10}\end{bmatrix}.$$